# How to tell if a DOS batch script is being run by task scheduler?

Tags: task-scheduler, batch-processing

How can a DOS Batch command file determine if it is being run by Task Scheduler?

Comment: You could output the script results in a log file with timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

If you control both the batch and the scheduled task, you could configure it to use a parameter.

Example - in the Scheduled Task, on the Action, you could define a parameter like: `/ScheduledTask`

In the batch file, you could check for the existence of the command-line parameter:

`if /i %1==/ScheduledTask set RUN_BY_TASK_SCHEDULER=1`

---

#### Related:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140228-00/?p=1633
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815035/determine-if-script-was-launched-manually-or-by-task-scheduler

Answer (score 0):

maybe if the task was scheduled with another account, local or domain.

Inserting an IF based on enviroment variables like %userdomain% or %username%

Regards!